# Marshal.SizeOf выдает странные результаты при использовании с массивом

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый день, не могу понять почему при использовании `Marshal.SizeOf()` для типа, где есть переменная массив, функция возвращает другие значения.
К примеру, у меня на руках структура:

```
struct MyStruct {
    public int[] Value;
}
```

При использовании `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MyStruct))` выдает 4, как я понял, берется размер типа массива, то есть `int` (4 байта, всё верно).
Но если я пишу нечто следующее:

```
MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct() { Value = new int[] { 1, 2 } };
Marshal.SizeOf(myStruct);
```

Очевидно, что результат должен быть 8, но выдает 4.
Есть ли способ декларировать массив определенной длины в структуре, чтобы `Marshal.SizeOf` выдавал правильные результаты?

Comment: во втором случае Вы смотрите размер указателя. А ему все равно, что там внутри структуры или массива.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int[]` — ссылочный тип, он хранится как ссылка, а не «встроен» в исходный тип. Вот вы и получаете размер ссылки (а не размер `int`).

`Marshal.SizeOf` выдал правильный результат.

---

Если вы реально хотите держать ваш буфер *внутри* структуры, вам придётся прибегнуть к unsafe-коду и [массивам фиксированного размера](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zycewsya.aspx):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
unsafe struct MyStruct
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public fixed int Value[2];
}
```

Для такой структуры `Marshal.SizeOf<MyStruct>()` выдаст желаемое 8.

Не забудьте отметить в свойствах проекта Build → General → Allow unsafe code. Но такое нужно делать лишь для случая хитрого interop'а, в нормальных случаях избегайте такого кода.

---

**Обновление:**

Если вам реально всё равно, как именно выглядит распределение памяти в управляемом коде, а нужно лишь лишь правильное маршаллирование в нативный код, вам подойдёт явное указание способа маршаллирования:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 2)]
    public int[] Value;
}
```

---

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Работа со структурами в C#](https://habrahabr.ru/post/114953/).

Comment: Да, подойдет явное указание размера, спасибо!

Comment: @MarkKhromov: Пожалуйста! Но всё же, посмотрите в сторону варианта с кастомным маршаллированием.